# Drupal's webform module isn't using the webform.api.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm working with the Webform module of Drupal 7 and I'm trying to modify the `hook_webform_submission_presave` in the *webform.api.php* , but it seems that the module is not using this file because I've made modifications but doesn't change anything.

Do I have to say to Drupal in any place to use this file? Or what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I hope that you know that you shouldn't change module files directly, but to add hook function to your module and change that "hook" at beginning of function name with your module machine name.

Second, you have to clear all the caches so Drupal will re-scan your module and figure out that there is new hook function and start using it.

So, you have to create your own module first:

https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Don't be scared - It's just a folder with an info file describing your module and module file it self (in minimal case).

Then, if your module is called "anna" you should create a function inside your module file and name it:

anna_webform_submissions_presave()

And clear the cache - after that Drupal should start calling your hook function.

Comment: Thanks... Sorry I'm new on it... How do I have to add the hook function? I want to modify the `hook_webform_submission_presave` function because I need to modify the sid before saving it to the database. @MilanG

Comment: Thanks again, I have my module now. The reason why I asked this question is because I want to modify the sid of the webform_submission before saving it. I've tried to do the following but it doesn't works:

Comment: `function uvic_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {

 $result = db_select('webform_submissions', 'sid')
    ->fields('sid')
    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
    ->orderBy('sid', DESC)
    ->range(0,1)
    ->execute();
    ->fetchAssoc();
 if($submission->nid == $node->nid){
  if ($result) {
    $submission->['sid'] =  $result['sid'] + 1;
  } else {
    $submission->['sid'] = 1; 
  }
}
  $component_id = 4;
  $submission->data[$component_id][0] = 'uvic';
}` @MilanG

Comment: Uh, it's hard to debug this way. Try printing out that $submissions before and after your change and check if everything is changed the way you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Modules don't use their `.api.php` files. These file are there for documentation purpose. That's [the standard way for documenting hook definitions](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards/docs#hooks).

Comment: Thanks! I've asked the question again, can you please take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861851/use-hook-webform-submission-presave-to-edit-the-sid-of-a-drupal-webform @Pierre Buyle